# Spring with MyBatis: expected single matching bean but found 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I've been using Spring with MyBatis and it's been working really well for a single database. I ran into difficulties when trying to add another database (see [reproducible example on Github](https://github.com/alexwoolford/mybatis-spring-multiple-mysql-reproducible-example)).

I'm using Spring Java configuration (i.e. not XML). Most of the examples I've seen show how to achieve this using XML.

I have two data configuration classes (A & B) like this:

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan("io.woolford.database.mapper")
public class DataConfigDatabaseA {

    @Bean(name="dataSourceA")
    public DataSource dataSourceA() throws SQLException {
        SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + dbHostA + "/" + dbDatabaseA);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUserA);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPasswordA);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSourceA());
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }
}
```

Two mappers, and a service that autowires the mappers:

```
@Service
public class DbService {

    @Autowired
    private DbMapperA dbMapperA;

    @Autowired
    private DbMapperB dbMapperB;

    public List<Record> getDabaseARecords(){
        return dbMapperA.getDatabaseARecords();
    }

    public List<Record> getDabaseBRecords(){
        return dbMapperB.getDatabaseBRecords();
    }

}
```

The application won't start:

```
Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': 
  Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: 
      No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: 
        expected single matching bean but found 2: dataSourceB,dataSourceA
```

I've read that it's possible to use the `@Qualifier` annotation to disambiguate the autowiring, though I wasn't sure where to add it.

Can you see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you post the complete error message ? Usually spring tells you the autowired field and the bean causing the error.

Comment: `@Qaulifier("name_of_bean")` can be placed before or after the `@Autowired` annotation of the particular field you want to target I believe

Comment: Thanks @Ben75. I posted the full output to: https://gist.github.com/alexwoolford/1f3e799deb3be32a4356

Comment: I think you are facing a problem caused by spring-boot auto-configuration strategy. I guess that the bean 'dataSourceInitializer' defined in some spring-boot starter module is expecting -by default- one single datasource bean. (I'm not a spring-boot, nor mybatis expert... so I can't help anymore)

Comment: @BretC: I added `@Qualifier("dataSourceA")` and the expected bean error changed: "expected single matching bean but found 2: sqlSessionFactoryA,sqlSessionFactoryB". I believe it's only possible to add one qualifier to `@Autowired`, so perhaps I need to add a name to `@Component` and use that as a qualifier?

Comment: Perhaps this will help... http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

Comment: I added `@Primary` to the DataSource and SqlSessionFactory beans in the DataConfigDatabaseA class and it magically started working! However, it doesn't work when `@Primary` is added to DataConfigDatabaseB instead. This is okay as a workaround, though I don't think it's a good rule-of-thumb because there doesn't seem to be a rule to determine which beans should be annotated with `@Primary`.

Comment: Have you tried to create the dataSourceInitializer(s) manually in the config instead of letting them be created implicitly?

Comment: Thanks again, @FlorianSchaetz. I added this to DataConfig classes:

`@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(final DataSource dataSource) {
    final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return initializer;
}`

It didn't work. I need to learn more about Spring to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, we put each mapper in its own folder:

```
src/main/java/io/woolford/database/mapper/a/DbMapperA.java
src/main/java/io/woolford/database/mapper/c/DbMapperB.java
```

We then created two `DataConfig` classes, one for each database. The `@MapperScan` annotation resolved the `expected single matching bean but found 2` issue.

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan(value = {"io.woolford.database.mapper.a"}, sqlSessionFactoryRef="sqlSessionFactoryA")
public class DataConfigDatabaseA {
```

It was necessary to add the `@Primary` annotation to the beans in one of the `DataConfig` classes:

```
@Bean(name="dataSourceA")
@Primary
public DataSource dataSourceA() throws SQLException {
    ...
}

@Bean(name="sqlSessionFactoryA")
@Primary
public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactoryA() throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

Thanks to everyone who helped. No doubt, there's more than one way to do this. I did try `@Qualifier` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` as recommended by @eduardlofitskyi and @GeminiKeith, but that generated some further errors.

In case it's useful, the solution that worked for us is posted here: https://github.com/alexwoolford/mybatis-spring-multiple-mysql-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use two data sources at same time and they are not primary and secondary, you should disable `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` by `@EnableAutoConfiguration(excludes = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` on your application annotated by `@SpringBootApplication`. Afterwards, you can create your own `SqlSessionFactory` and bundle your own `DataSource`. If you also want to use `DataSourceTransactionManager`, you should do that too.

In this case, you haven't disabled `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`, so spring framework will try to `@Autowired` only one `DataSource` but got two, error occurs.

As what I've said before, you should disable `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` and configure it manually.

You can disable data source auto configuration as following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class YourApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main (String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And if you are really want to use multiple databases at same time, I suggest you to registering proper bean manually, such as:

```
package xyz.cloorc.boot.mybatis;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.support.SqlSessionDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class SimpleTest {

    private DataSource dsA;
    private DataSource dsB;

    @Bean(name = "dataSourceA")
    public DataSource getDataSourceA() {
        return dsA != null ? dsA : (dsA = new BasicDataSource());
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSourceB")
    public DataSource getDataSourceB() {
        return dsB != null ? dsB : (dsB = new BasicDataSource());
    }

    @Bean(name = "sqlSessionFactoryA")
    public SqlSessionFactory getSqlSessionFactoryA() throws Exception {
        // set DataSource to dsA
        return new SqlSessionFactoryBean().getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "sqlSessionFactoryB")
    public SqlSessionFactory getSqlSessionFactoryB() throws Exception {
        // set DataSource to dsB
        return new SqlSessionFactoryBean().getObject();
    }
}

@Repository
public class SimpleDao extends SqlSessionDaoSupport {

    @Resource(name = "sqlSessionFactoryA")
    SqlSessionFactory factory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        setSqlSessionFactory(factory);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
        super.setSqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactory);
    }

    public <T> T get (Object id) {
        return super.getSqlSession().selectOne("sql statement", "sql parameters");
    }
}
```

Comment: What a helpful answer!!! Either `@EnableAutoConfiguration(excludes = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)` or `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)`.

Comment: Thanks! spent an hour for this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Qualifier` annotation

The problem is that you have two the same type beans in Spring container. And when you try autowire beans, Spring cannot resolve which bean inject to field

The `@Qualifier` annotation is the main way to work with qualifiers. It can be applied alongside `@Autowired` or `@Inject` at the point of injection to specify which bean you want to be injected.

So, your DbService should look like this:

```
    @Service
    public class DbService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSourceA")
    private DbMapperA dbMapperA;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSourceB")
    private DbMapperB dbMapperB;

    public List<Record> getDabaseARecords(){
        return dbMapperA.getDatabaseARecords();
    }

    public List<Record> getDabaseBRecords(){
        return dbMapperB.getDatabaseBRecords();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and could not start my Spring Boot application, and by renaming the offending class and all the layers that dealt with it, strangely the application started successfully.

I have the classes `UOMService`, `UOMServiceImpl` `UOMRepository` and `UOMRepositoryImpl`. I renamed them to be `UomService`, `UomServiceImpl`, `UomRepository` and `UomRepositoryImpl` and that solved the problem!