# Spring Boot with multiple datasources and in memory database

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to set up Spring Boot to work with multiple datasources. I have followed the [instructions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html) for setting up two datasources and set one of them primary.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"my.postgres.repositories"}
                       entityManagerFactoryRef="postgresEntitymanager"
                       transactionManagerRef="postgresTransactionManager")
public class PgConfig {
@Primary
@Bean(name="postgresDS")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.postgres")
public DataSource postgresDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
@Primary
@Bean(name="postgresEntityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean postgresEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    return builder.dataSource(postgresDataSource())
            .packages("my.postgres.domain")
            .persistenceUnit("postgresPersistenceUnit")
            .build();
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "postgresTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager postgresTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("postgresEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
```

I have a second configuration class for oracle which lacks the @Primary annotation but is very similar. I have also added this to my main class to exclude datasource auto configuration.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

The problem that I'm facing is this setup doesn't allow my Integration tests that are supposed to run against an H2 databse to open a connection...

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
```

I'm using a separate application.properties file under src/integrationtest/resources which contains

```
spring.jpa.database=H2
```

How do I get my integration tests to use H2 for the repositories that I'm using when running my tests?

If I don't include my custom datasources everything seems to work fine.

Thanks

Comment: Please look at my answer [Spring with MyBatis: expected single matching bean but found 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36842458/5619827). It could be help. This will help you to build real multiple data sources in single application.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own test's configuration with `h2` database but use other database in production. You've excluded `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` in your spring application class, but it's usefull in your integration tests.

One simple solution is using a different spring application class only for your integrating tests without excluding `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` or just implement your own `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` and enable it. You can decide when will your own `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` be enabled or not within your own implementation. For example, if there are `junit` or `spring-test` exists in your `classpath` it will be enabled, otherwise will be disabled. This requires the `junit` or `spring-test` not going to be included in production, which can be handled by dependencies management such as maven.